# How can I handle browser alert

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

[image]

I do not understand how to click allow button.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe",options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://virtual.eventbuizz.com/event/what-is-app-virtualization--part-1--remote-apps-8862/streaming")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys("aha@eventbuizz.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='btn btn-default btn-submit']").click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='slidebox sliboxtheme_3']").click()
```

Comment: Please, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007699/how-to-allow-or-deny-notification-geo-location-microphone-camera-pop-up.

Answer (score -1):

While working in a professional [testing company](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company), we have developed test scripts for various applications which require handling alerts for camera and mic.
You can resolve this issue by adding argument "use-fake-ui-for-media-stream" in your chrome option list.

Attached is screenshot for your reference-

[image]